# How can I have access to one item's variables in another class that is not related with it?

Tags: java

I'm new to java and i was searching about this for a long time. How can I have access to the item's b variables in class Player??(the cod i'm posting is a part of my full programm so don't mind if you see methods or variables that are not declared in the following code)

```
import java.util.Random;
public abstract class Player {
 private int x, y;
 private String name;
 private int pNumber;
 private int mLine;
 private int tLine;
 private boolean possession;
 private int c;
 private int f = 0;
 private int i = 0;


 public int getPlx() {
  return x;
 }
 public void setPlx(int x) {
  this.x = x;
 }
 public int getPly() {
  return y;
 }
 public void setPly(int y) {
  this.y = y;
 }
 public String getPName() {
  return name;
 }
 public void setPName(String name) {
  this.name = name;
 }
 public int getPNum() {
  return pNumber;
 }
 public void setPNum(int pNumber) {
  this.pNumber = pNumber;
 }
 public int getMLine() {
  return mLine;
 }
 public void setMLine(int mLine) {
  this.mLine = mLine;
 }
 public int getLine() {
  return tLine;
 }
 public void setTLine(int tLine) {
  this.tLine = tLine;
 }
 public boolean getPos() {
  return possession;
 }
 public void setPos(boolean possession) {
  this.possession = possession;
 }

 private Random rand = new Random();

 public void Move() { //me8odos metakinisis
  c = rand.nextInt(2);
  if (c == 0) {
   y++;
  } else {
   y--;
  }
 }
 public void Pass() {
  if (this.possession == true) {
   c = rand.nextInt(10);
   while ((f == 0) && (i < 10)) {
    if (main.barcelona.get(i).name == this.name) {}
   }
  }
 }
 public abstract void SpecialMove();
}

public class Ball {
 private int x, y;
 private Player formerP = null;
 private Player currentP = null;

 public Ball(int x, int y, Player formerP, Player currentP) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.formerP = formerP;
  this.currentP = currentP;
 }

 public int getBX() {
  return x;
 }
 public void setBX(int x) {
  this.x = x;
 }
 public int getBY() {
  return y;
 }
 public void setBY(int y) {
  this.y = y;
 }

 void Assign(Player playerP) {
  int px = playerP.getPlx();
  if (this.currentP == null) {
   if (((this.x - px <= 1) || (px - this.x) <= 1) 
       && ((this.x - px <= 1) || (px - this.x) = 1)) {
    this.currentP = playerP;
    this.formerP.possession = false;
    playerP.possession = true;

    if (this.currentP.team == this.formerP.team) {
     int pass = this.currentP.getPasses();
     pass++;
     this.currentP.setPasses(pass);
    } else {
     int mistake = this.currentP.getMistakes();
     mistake++;
     this.currentP.setMistakes(mistake);
    }
   }
  }
  this.formerP = this.currentP;
  this.currentP = null;
  this.formerP = null;
 }
}
```

Comment: you can´t magicly acces these variabels if you don´t have a variable reference to an existing instance of the class whos variables you want to acces or accessing static variables. (Also you should stick to javas naming convention which says that method should start with a lower letter)

Comment: so i have to declare the variables of class Ball as static?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to instantiate the class `Ball` in the `Player` class *and* you would like to ensure that all players are playing with the one and only ball, then consider making `Ball` a [Singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

> In software engineering, the singleton pattern is a design pattern that restricts the instantiation of a class to one object. This is useful when exactly one object is needed to coordinate actions across the system.

```
public class Ball {
    private static Ball singletonBall;

    private int x;
    private int y;
    private Player formerP;
    private Player currentP;


    public static Ball getSingletonBall() {
        if(singletonBall == null){
            singletonBall = new Ball();
        }
        return singletonBall;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }


    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }


    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }


    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }


    public Player getFormerP() {
        return formerP;
    }


    public void setFormerP(Player formerP) {
        this.formerP = formerP;
    }


    public Player getCurrentP() {
        return currentP;
    }


    public void setCurrentP(Player currentP) {
        this.currentP = currentP;
    }
}
```

Comment: where did xCoordinate occur?

Comment: Have you assigned the ball object to the player object as shown?

Comment: @kafes13 I have added I declaration for the `xCoordinate` variable. Sorry I assumed declaration was understood.

Comment: I dont create the item Ball in class Player, thus i cant use the getters... so any other ideas?

Comment: @kafes13 Use the Singleton Design Pattern for your Ball

Answer (score 0):

If there is something that you need inside Player that you will be using often that won't change throughout the life of the Player object (or sub object in your case), then you might as well pass it to a local variable through the Player constructor.

Let's assume Item B is the Ball and you have a Ball class.

So in player (or sub player) declare your object you want access to:

```
class Player {
    Ball ball;

    public Player(Ball ball) {
       this.ball = ball;
    }
```

Or if it's just something that you'll be using infrequently or something that's value will change (more likely with a ball), then create a method to perform what you need on the Player object.

```
class Player {
.
.
.
.
.
    public void dribble(Ball ball) {
    // do something with the ball
        ball.setPosition(10, 20);
        ball.update();
    }
}
```

Then whatever instantiates Player can access that method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Player player = new Player();
    Ball ball = new Ball();
    player.dribble(ball);
}
```

Comment: i want to change the values of the item Ball in class Player which does not create a new item of type Ball

Comment: In that case, my second example is the way to go about it. Whatever is instantiating your Player and your Ball, then you should call a method in the Player, that changes the value of the Ball.

Comment: I changed a bit of the code above just to show you what I mean. Notice how I am able to call methods on the ball, by passing it in as a parameter to the player. It's important that these are methods in the ball class that you are calling, from the Player class.

Answer (score 0):

try BallClassName.getX();
You may have to make getX static